# Exception escalates despite a catch block of Exceptions type

Tags: c#, exception

I have a List of TCP sockets I write data to. If the writing fails, I remove it from the list and just carry on.

At least thats the plan. What happens is, that when a client disconnects, the SocketException escalates and the program crashes, even though that exception is handled. The code is below:

```
// sockets is type List<Socket>
foreach (Socket s in sockets)
{
  String jsonString = skeleton.Marshall();
  byte[] jsonBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

  try
  {
    s.Send(jsonBytes); // boom! System.Net.Sockets.SocketException!
  }
  catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException except)
  {
    sockets.Remove(s);
    Console.WriteLine(except.StackTrace);
  }
  catch (Exception except)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(except.StackTrace);
  }
}
```

I don't get why any exception could go through this. I didn't look at the console output because Visual Studio clears that when an exception occurs (at least I didn't see anything meaningful over there)

Thanks for your help!

#### Edit

As Sebastian Negraszus pointed out, I can't directly remove the Socket from the List, so the code now is

```
List<Socket> remove = new List<Socket>();

// sockets still is of type List<Socket>
foreach (Socket s in sockets)
{
    String jsonString = skeleton.Marshall();
    byte[] jsonBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

    try
    {
        s.Send(jsonBytes);
    }
    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException except)
    {
        remove.Add(s);
        Console.WriteLine(except.StackTrace);
    }
    catch (Exception except)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(except.StackTrace);
    }
}

foreach (Socket s in remove)
{
    sockets.Remove(s);
}
```

However, even if the Socket is not removed from the list, it should just escalate here.

#### Edit 2

This code runs in an event handler, while sockets is being filled in the main Thread, so I assumed the lack of locking caused problems. However, after adding locks, the error still appeared.

main thread:

```
// ...
sockets = new List<Socket>();
delegateFoo += handlerFunction;
// ...
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 20001);
tcpListener.Start();

while (true) {
    Socket s = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
    lock (sockets) {
        sockets.Add(s);
    }
}
```

handler function:

```
// ...generate skeleton...
lock (sockets)
{
    foreach (Socket s in sockets)
    {
        String jsonString = skeleton.Marshall();
        byte[] jsonBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

        try
        {
            s.Send(jsonBytes);
        }
        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException except)
        {
            remove.Add(s);
            Console.WriteLine(except.StackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(except.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    foreach (Socket s in remove)
    {
        sockets.Remove(s);
    }
}
```

Bad luck though, the Exception still escalates (at least I think so, the program interrupts in VS and this little window occurs saying "SocketException occured" (I use the German version, so the wording might be different).
The error can be triggered by connecting twice using putty and closing one of the two puttys. The next time Send() is called - boom.

#### Edit 3: Exception details

I'm sorry these are in German. Translations:

- "... ist aufgetreten" = "... occured"
- "bei" = "at"
- message = "An existing connection has been aborted/terminated by the host computer"

  ```
  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ist aufgetreten.
    _HResult=-2147467259
    _message=Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
    HResult=-2147467259
    IsTransient=false
    Message=Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
    Source=System
    ErrorCode=10053
    NativeErrorCode=10053
    StackTrace:
     bei System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
    InnerException:
  ```

And yes, I only Send() once in my program.

#### Edit 4: Visual Studio weirdness

Okay, it's Visual Studio being weird. I can uncheck the "break on Exceptions of this type" checkbox and then it just continues. So the exception didn't escalate, but nevertheless made the program stop.

I don't get why you would want to break on handled exceptions by default. I figured that if I uncheck that the program just faults. If you have a better solution, I'd be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: Could it be erroring when you are assigning your variables?

Comment: I don't see any exceptions not being caught here.  Most likely if you had the details of this uncatchable exception it would explain exactly what's happening and why speculation outside of having these details is pointless.

Comment: @DavidBeaumont: well, VS says that the error occurs in send and it's a SocketException. I don't think so. I added some more code to illustrate the problem, though.

Comment: @Will: There is a SocketException in a try block that is followed by a catch block catching SocketExceptions. Am I missing something here? I also added some more info to the original question.

Comment: The exception's stack trace is required for diagnostics.  The most obvious thing you might overlook is that you asked the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown.  Use Debug + Exceptions, untick the Thrown checkboxes.

Comment: @HansPassant I added the stack trace. I don't know which dialogue you mean, though.

Comment: The exception handler dialog has a "copy exception details to the clipboard" link.  Use it.  Otherwise, catch it and call ToString on it.  You clipped out the inner exception.  Don't hide information from the people trying to help you, it doesn't generally work well.

Comment: @Will That is what you see after Edit #3.

Comment: @Will Sorry for not reading you comment properly. InnerException is null. I don't have access to the code atm, but I remember seeing that it is null and that I wondered that it didn't write 'null' there. I didn't clip it out, it just was emptystring.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uncheck "break on exceptions of this type" (or whatever it's called in English). Works fine afterwards.

Comment: Okay I don't know who exacly voted this down, but after unchecking this box the program actually went into the catch block. I thought this behaviour was weird, too, but this is just rude.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `sockets` is a `List<T>`? You cannot modify the list with `sockets.Remove(s);` while still inside the `foreach` loop, because this invalidates the enumerator. The next iteration causes an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: good point, I changed the code so this is fixed; didn't remove the exception escalation though. Any other ideas?